# Is it possible to find $f(n)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Is it possible to find $f(n)$?

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{k}f(n)=2×3^k$$

I dont know, how to begin.

Comment: This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  They have a nice formula for finite sums

Comment: @Ross Millikan Is it possible, can you write formula? Are the users' answer correct?

Comment: Yes, they are right

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}f(n)=2×3^k$$
Implies that for $k>1$, 
$$f(k) = \sum_{n=1}^{k}f(n) - \sum_{n=1}^{k-1}f(n) = 2×3^k - 2×3^{k-1} = 4×3^{k-1}$$
and $f(1) = 6$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says your answer is wrong

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake and edited my answer. There's a special case at $f(1)$, because $\sum_{n=1}^{0}f(n)$ doesn't make sense

Comment: I don't understand, for $k=1$ your formula is wrong.

Comment: What is $f(n)?$

Comment: for k=1 the summation make no sense thats why $\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{0}$

Comment: $f(n)$ is the function $f$ evaluated at a variable $n$

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{k}(4×3^{n-1})=2(3^k-1)≠2×3^k$

Comment: I just explained in a previous comment and in the answer that for $n=1$ $f(n) \neq 2 × 3^n$, it's a different function. Please read my answer

Comment: No, I find only function $\sum_{n=1}^{k}f(n)=2×3^k$

Comment: Yes, and you can use that expression to find $f(n)$, just as I showed you

Comment: I don't understand still yet, $k=1 \rightarrow 6=4$

Comment: No, that's not what I said. What I said was that $k=1 \implies f(k) = 6$ and $k>1 \implies f(k) = 4×3^{k-1}$

Answer (score 0):

You jsut need to rewrite your formula...
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}f(n)=2×3^k$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}f(n)+\sum_{n=k}^{k}f(n)=2×3^k$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}f(n)+f(k)=2×3^k$$
$$f(k)=2×3^k-\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}f(n)$$
$$f(k)=2×3^k-2\times 3 ^{k-1}$$
Or if you wanna use n
$$f(n)=2×3^n-2\times 3 ^{n-1}=4\times 3 ^{n-1}$$

For n>1

Comment: Finally, $f(n)=???$

Comment: the same as f(k) @User184613 you can use k or n m l whatever